# Component name of hideable menus

Tags: gui-design, menu, component

How are the menus you can open and close (like in Blender) called?

[image: Property panel of the Blender 3D view]

I assume that this GUI design concept will also have a pretty name I can google more information with but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webdevelopment these are called [accordions](https://www.google.nl/search?q=accordion%20css&oq=accordion%20css&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65.3135j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Can you source an article or website rather than a Google search result?

Comment: Some links: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI), http://wiki.openelement.com/en/index.php?title=Accordion_Menu